# Listen to blockchain events in js

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, events

I want all js clients to react on new event being stored to blockchain:

```
contract MainContract{
    event Evt(address indexed _sender,string jsn);
    function deposit(string jsn) returns (int256) {
        Evt(msg.sender, jsn);
    }
}
```

Here I expect watch callback to be executed.

```
    var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at("0xe45866ac5d51067ce292bc656c790e94ddcf0766");
    var myEvent = contract.Evt({},{fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
    myEvent.watch(function(error, result){
        console.log("on watch"); 
        console.log(arguments);
    });
    // this call saves event data successfully!
    contract.deposit('hello there',function (res) {
        console.log(arguments)
    });
```

But I don't see 'on watch' in my console.
Is this possible? How can I do this? Any example?

UPDATE: my best guess right now that this is metamask.io problem (https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/issues/792)

UPDATE2: Looks like a bug in ethereum kernel, some people report same experience: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14670

Comment: For your comments it is working, but you can't see the "on watch" message no?

Comment: 'On watch' call back is not executed.

Comment: So if 'myEvent' is not undefined, and you can call '.watch', yes maybe is a problem with event.watch. With filters.watch have errors very similars,  but try to ' put      if(!error)
         console.log(result);
     else
         console.error(error);
  }) '

Comment: myEvent is not underfined, i have no js errors. error is not null, callback is not called at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my problem: I used wrong contract address. Note, that **API wouldn't let you know that contract address is incorrect**!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using truffle, the deployed instance should have the event so you can listen to changes:

```
let Contract = artifacts.require('./Contract.sol');

contract('Contract', accounts => {

    let MyEvent;

    Contract.deployed().then(instance => {
        MyEvent = instance.SolidityEventMethod({});

        MyEvent.watch((error, result) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }

            console.log(result);
        });
    });

    it('should do something and trigger event', () => {
        return Contract.deployed().then(instance => {
            return instance.myEventTriggeringFunction();
        }).then(res => {
            // at this point the MyEvent.watch method should have logged the result
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the "problem" it is due to asynchronous functions.
A workaround might be this:

```
 var contract;
 window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

        contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);
        var myEvent = contract.Evt({},{fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
        myEvent.watch(function(error, result){
            console.log("on watch");
            console.log(result);
            console.log(result.args);
        });

    } else {
        console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!')
    }
})


function callDeposit(){
    contract.deposit('hello there',function (error, result) {
            console.log(result);
    });
}
```

Also in your code the variable arguments is `undefined`.
Hope this help.

Comment: I am already using skeleton like this. And you can see from my code that I register watch callback before successfull call to .deposit().

Comment: variable arguments can't be undefined, because its js standard variable